# Unable to create a login page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

First of all I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create a login page for my project. I made the database there are `Id` and `Pass` in my `Students` table.

I'm trying to login with using the credentials, but i think  I made a mistake somewhere and whatever i write to `Id` and `Pass` fields, and even if I leave them blank, I can get through the login page.

Here's my code hope you can help me thanks from now.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        try{
                con.Open();
                string IdText = user.Text;
                string PassText = pass.Text;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(Id, '') AS Id, ISNULL(Pass,'') AS Pass FROM Students WHERE Id = @Id and Pass = @Pass", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", IdText));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Pass", PassText));

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");

                try{
                    dr.Read();
                    if (dr["Id"].ToString().Trim() == IdText && dr["Pass"].ToString().Trim() == PassText) {
                        Label4.Text = "This message won't Display";
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    Label4.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
                }

                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Label4.Text = (ex.Message);
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: What your web.config says regarding access?

Comment: Why is there a Response.Redirect("Main.aspx"); in the middle? That is: If main.aspx is the page you have "behind a login" then you are sending all users to it before you're checking if their username/password is valid.

Comment: Yes im trying to send people to that page where should i put that

Comment: Probably put the redirect in the block that checks if the `Id` and `PassText` are correct. After all, if they are a valid user, redirect them, otherwise, don't.

Comment: Do you mean the if block ? i tried at there but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your code with following

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try{
            con.Open();
            string IdText = user.Text;
            string PassText = pass.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(Id, '') AS Id, ISNULL(Pass,'') AS Pass FROM Students WHERE Id = @Id and Pass = @Pass", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", IdText));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pass", PassText));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();       

            dr.Read();
            if (dr["Id"].ToString().Trim() == IdText && dr["Pass"].ToString().Trim() == PassText) {
                Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label4.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
            }             

            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Label4.Text = (ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you its working only invalid username or pass part is not working but at least i can log on =)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="myLogin.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

On Authentication you will need to do this:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
```

`userName`, I think in your code is `IdText`

Comment: as mentioned in previous comments you will need to do something about this in the middle of your code:  Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");

Comment: i have something like that at there   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: How about your authorization elements?

Comment: I don't know what to write to web.config theres no authorization element there :/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use try/catch blocks to control flow of execution - that is a very bad practice, and you're doing it twice in one function. If you can explicitly test for 'error' conditions (such as `dr["Id"]` being null) then do so instead of relying on exceptions.